# How to count of fields with the same value in elastic.js (elasticsearch)?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nosql

I have a list of communities. And I need to create aggregation query which will count all data which have the same title.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "56161cb3cbdad2e3b437fdc3",
    "_type": "Comunity",
    "name": "public",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "sonder",
        "creationDate": "2015-08-22T03:43:28 -03:00",
        "quantity": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "vule",
        "creationDate": "2014-05-17T12:35:01 -03:00",
        "quantity": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "omer",
        "creationDate": "2015-01-31T04:54:19 -02:00",
        "quantity": 3
      },
      {
        "title": "sonder",
        "creationDate": "2014-05-22T05:09:36 -03:00",
        "quantity": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "56161cb3dae30517fc133cd9",
    "_type": "Comunity",
    "name": "static",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "vule",
        "creationDate": "2014-07-01T06:32:06 -03:00",
        "quantity": 5
      },
      {
        "title": "vule",
        "creationDate": "2014-01-10T12:40:28 -02:00",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "title": "vule",
        "creationDate": "2014-01-09T09:33:11 -02:00",
        "quantity": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "56161cb32f62b522355ca3c8",
    "_type": "Comunity",
    "name": "public",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "vule",
        "creationDate": "2014-02-03T09:55:28 -02:00",
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "vule",
        "creationDate": "2015-01-23T09:14:22 -02:00",
        "quantity": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So desire result should be

```
[
  {
    title: vule,
    total: 6
  },
  {
    title: omer,
    total: 1
  },
  {
    title: sonder,
    total: 1
  }
]
```

I wrote some aggregation queries but it still not work. How can I get desire result?

PS: I tried to create nested aggregation

```
ejs.Request().size(0).agg(
        ejs.NestedAggregation('comunities')
            .path('data')
            .agg(
                ejs.FilterAggregation('sonder')
                    .filter(
                    ejs.TermsFilter('data.title', 'sonder')
                ).agg(
                ejs.ValueCountAggregation('counts')
                      .field('data.title')
)
            )
    );
```

Comment: Post your aggregation query.

Comment: Are you storing an array of objects in each document?

Comment: Please mention the solution you tried, the output you got and also the mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregations.

Now depending on your mapping there could be two ways of doing that:

**1. Your data field is stored as an subdocument**

You need to run a simple terms aggregation, which in RAW json looks like:

```
POST /test/test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Grouping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "data.title",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Your data field is stored as an [nested document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)**

You have to add a nested subaggregation before doing terms aggregation.

```
POST /test/test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Nest": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "data"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Grouping": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data.title",
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Both will output this:**

```
{
   "took": 125,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "Nest": {
         "doc_count": 9,
         "Grouping": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "vule",
                  "doc_count": 6            -- The Total count you're looking for
               },
               {
                  "key": "sonder",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "omer",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This, unfortunately, is just a raw query, but I imagine that it can be translated into [elastic.js](https://github.com/fullscale/elastic.js/) quite easily.

On top of that. If you're going to do aggregations, don't forget to set your fields, that you're doing aggregations on, as `not_analyzed`, because it will start counting individual tokens as in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html#aggregations-and-analysis)

I, myself, would store these documens as nested ones.

Example:

**Mappings:**

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "fields": {
                "stemmed": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzed": "standard"
                }
              }
            },
            "creationDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "quantity": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Test data:**

```
PUT /test/test/56161cb3cbdad2e3b437fdc3
{
  "name": "public",
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "sonder",
      "creationDate": "2015-08-22T03:43:28",
      "quantity": 0
    },
    {
      "title": "vule",
      "creationDate": "2014-05-17T12:35:01",
      "quantity": 0
    },
    {
      "title": "omer",
      "creationDate": "2015-01-31T04:54:19",
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "title": "sonder",
      "creationDate": "2014-05-22T05:09:36",
      "quantity": 3
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test/test/56161cb3dae30517fc133cd9
{
  "name": "static",
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "vule",
      "creationDate": "2014-07-01T06:32:06",
      "quantity": 5
    },
    {
      "title": "vule",
      "creationDate": "2014-01-10T12:40:28",
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "vule",
      "creationDate": "2014-01-09T09:33:11",
      "quantity": 3
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test/test/56161cb32f62b522355ca3c8
{
  "name": "public",
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "vule",
      "creationDate": "2014-02-03T09:55:28",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "title": "vule",
      "creationDate": "2015-01-23T09:14:22",
      "quantity": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Actual query:**

```
POST /test/test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Nest": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "data"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Grouping": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data.title",
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. `"size":0` means that I'm letting Elasticsearch output all possible terms and not limiting its output as described in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size).

> The `size` parameter can be set to define how many term buckets should
>   be returned out of the overall terms list. By default, the node
>   coordinating the search process will request each shard to provide its
>   own top `size` term buckets and once all shards respond, it will reduce
>   the results to the final list that will then be returned to the
>   client. This means that if the number of unique terms is greater than
>   `size`, the returned list is slightly off and not accurate (it could be
>   that the term counts are slightly off and it could even be that a term
>   that should have been in the top size buckets was not returned). If
>   set to `0`, the `size` will be set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Thank's but I need to count not just all documents but all objects in all documents so total's of "vule" have to be 6

Comment: I've updated answer. This query runs fine and does exactly what you need. Please see:
http://prntscr.com/8p1hem