# How to filter nested documents in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which looks like

```
  {
    "_id": "56161cb3cbdad2e3b437fdc3",
    "_type": "Comunity",
    "name": "public",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "sonder",
        "creationDate": "2015-08-22T03:43:28 -03:00",
        "quantity": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "vule",
        "creationDate": "2014-05-17T12:35:01 -03:00",
        "quantity": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "omer",
        "creationDate": "2015-01-31T04:54:19 -02:00",
        "quantity": 3
      },
      {
        "title": "sonder",
        "creationDate": "2014-05-22T05:09:36 -03:00",
        "quantity": 3
      }
    ]
  }
```

The mapping:

```
      comunityDocument": {
        "_source": {
          "includes": [
            "meta.*"
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "doc": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
              "data": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "properties": {
                  "title": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },                     
                  "creationDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                  },
                  "quantity": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "meta": {
            "include_in_all": false,
            "properties": {
              "expiration": {
                "type": "long",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "flags": {
                "type": "long",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "include_in_all": false
              },
              "rev": {
                "type": "string",
                "include_in_all": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

And my query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filterAgg": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "comunityDocument.doc.data",
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "comunityDocument.doc.data.quantity": [
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As result I have to get count of all "data" documents where quantity is equal 0 but I don't get it. The strange thing that nested aggregations works but not nested filters.

Comment: Is that the complete mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `comunityDocument` is the type, then the correct query should be

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filterAgg": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "doc.data",
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "doc.data.quantity": [
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct query to achieve that:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Nest": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "data"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Filtering": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "quantity": 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. You specify that you're going to work on Nested field
2. Apply term filter so it does filter subdocs where `quantity = 0`
3. Your query will bring back something like this:

I've used test data I provided in [question, you previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009794/how-to-count-of-fields-with-the-same-value-in-elastic-js-elasticsearch/33011118#33011118).

```
{
   "took": 44,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "Nest": {
         "doc_count": 9,
         "Filtering": {
            "doc_count": 3
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: interesting didn't know you could do this way